# Where can I find the ServerConnection class?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm doing function which encodes strings by RSA. I decided to base my code on this:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption_2.shtml

But, when I simply copy & paste code, everything is ok, except ServerConnection class, which is not found:

```
InputStream wej =ServerConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("remote_public.key");
```

Where I can find it? I have any hints in netbeans according to missing import. Googling for "ServerConnection" gives me everyting except anythin which at least looks like the one I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need ServerConnection class at all here. You are trying to access resource `remote_public.key` located where your classes are. It means that you can take any class you want (for example class where you are writing the code) and use it to access the resource.

For example if your class is named `"MyClass"`
just say:

`InputStream wej = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("remote_public.key")`

Answer (score 1):

`ServerConnection` is likely just an example class name within the shown code, used only for the purpose of a base for obtaining a resource from the classpath.

You should be able to replace this with the name of any class in your local project, assuming that you have a file called `remote_public.key` in the same package (folder) as the class that you reference.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess on my part: I'm try replacing "ServerConnection" with your class name. I think the example is assumed to be in a class named ServerConnection.